# Office 365 global address list show entries by user/group

Tags: active-directory, exchange, microsoft-office-365

I have active directory groups synced with my office 365 global address lists. I am trying to limit visibility of certain distribution groups to only be seen by certain users or groups.

Is there a way to set security permissions to limit who can see specific users or groups within the office 365 global address list?

Answer (score 0):

Is it hybrid deployment? Or there is no Exchange on-premises server?

Based on my experience, we could user Address Book Policy (ABP) to GAL segregation. Address book policies (ABPs) lets admins segment users into specific groups to provide customized views of the organization's global address list (GAL). The goal of an ABP is to provide a simpler mechanism for GAL segmentation (also known as GAL segregation) in organizations that require multiple GALs. **I would like to make it extremely clear that GAL Segmentation DOES NOT DELETE any mail enable objects. It just creates a filtered version of the GAL for the user.**

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/address-books/address-book-policies/address-book-policies
https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/05/17/notes-from-the-field-enabling-gal-segmentation-in-exchange-online/
https://www.azure365pro.com/how-to-implement-address-book-policies-in-office-365exchange-20132016-effectively/